# What are good solutions for managing multiple GitHub Repo Issues?

Tags: github, organization

I read this [blog entry](https://github.com/blog/959-issues-dashboard-for-organizations) and was looking for how to turn this feature on; being able to see all issues for my organization in one place. Anyone know?

I also found [this](http://huboard.com/), but I need it for our internal github enterprise edition as well.

Any other solutions people are using?

Comment: You should probably contact GitHub support: https://github.com/contact. If you have the enterprise edition, I guess it comes with some special support.

Comment: I will contact them. I'll also clarify my question to see if anyone has suggestions for other apps like huboard.

Comment: GitHub support helped me find out how to get to it. It's there in both github.com and GitHub Enterprise: "If you go to your dashboard page - https://github.com while logged in - you can switch your account context view using the drop-down menu in the upper left corner. Switch to one of your organizations and then click on Issues in the top menu bar. That should bring up all the Issues across all the repositories in that organization."

Comment: You can write a proper answer and answer the question yourself. You might have to wait a bit though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GitHub support helped me find out how to get to it. It's there in both github.com and GitHub Enterprise: "*If you go to your dashboard page - github.com while logged in - you can switch your account context view using the drop-down menu in the upper left corner. Switch to one of your organizations and then click on Issues in the top menu bar. That should bring up all the Issues across all the repositories in that organization.*"

Answer (score 1):

GitHub officially released a GitHub Issue's dashboard that allows you to easily manage issues across repositories: https://github.com/issues. To get issues for a specific organization you can add `user: ORGANIZATION_NAME` to the search field.

Here is a short post by Zach Holman announcing this feature in October 2014: https://github.com/blog/1901-managing-issues-and-pull-requests-across-repositories